# Get error result when search match for only one time

Tags: regex, perl, match

I wanted to search a string that matched exact times in another string, while I met some problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test="abc1234abc5678abcdef910";
my $cut_seq="abc";

print $test,"\tone time\n" if($test=~/$cut_seq{1}/);

print $test,"\tmore than one times\n" if($test=~/$cut_seq{1,}/);
```

I expected the result:

```
abc1234abc5678abcdef910 more than one times
```

But the result showed as:

```
abc1234abc5678abcdef910 one time
abc1234abc5678abcdef910 more than one times
```

I also tried this:

```
print $test,"\tone time\n" if($test=~/$cut_seq{0,1}/);
print $test,"\tone time\n" if($test=~/$cut_seq{1,1}/);
print $test,"\tmore than one times\n" if($test=~/$cut_seq{1,}/);
```

But nothing changed. I just wonder why it can't match exact times. If something matches two times it will also match one time, then what's the difference of {1}, {1,}, {1,1}, {1,2}. I don't get the point to create these different forms.

Comment: FYI: `{1,}` doesn't mean "more than one time" but "one or more times"

Comment: @TOto, I am sorrry for that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If something matches two times it also matches one time. That's why your "one time" match always kicks in.

The easiest approach, I think, is to simply split at your `$cut_seq` and check the number of splitted elements.

```perl
my $test="abc1234abc5678abcdef910";
my $cut_seq="abc";
my @elts= split /$cut_seq/, $test;
print scalar(@elts)-1," times\n";
```

P.S. This does not count '$cut_seq` at the end of the string - sorry! You'll have to append something which will not be part of your sequence like:

```perl
my $test="abc1234abc5678abcdef910";
my $cut_seq="abc";
my @elts= split /$cut_seq/, $test . chr(0);
print scalar(@elts)-1," times\n";
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Your solution could be an easier way to do this. I just wondered why it can't match exact times. If something matches two times it will also match one time, then what's the difference of `{1}, {1,}, {1,2}`. I don't get the point to create these different forms.

Comment: `/a{2,3}/` will match all of `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa` and so on. But it wil not match `ababa`. The `{…}` part means to repeat the previos "atom". So with your `$cut_seq` being `abc`, `/$cut_seq{2,3}/` will not match at all in `xabcxabcxabcx`. It would only match for example `xabcabcabcx`.